# Pointers, bison and yacc

Tags: c, pointers, bison, yacc

I'm learning bison/yacc (and reviewing some c as well) and trying to build a json parser as simple test project.

Using the terminology found on http://www.json.org/ I have a struct pair that represents a string/value pair and a struct object representing an object that has a members field that contains basically a pointer to a linked list of pairs.

I have a simple c function (create_pair) that returns a new pair. I noticed a weird behaviour that I'm not able to explain:

- If I call such function from the "main" and I print the memory address of returned structs their address is always different.
- If I call the very same function inside a bison "action" I see that my function returns a pointer that happens to reside always on the very same memory address.

Does this make any sense?

Details/Code follow:

here's the code (the link, contains a list of 4 pastebin links pointing to the four different files included in the "project"):

- http://pastebin.com/k272vVb5

you can compile and run it with:

```
lex t.l
yacc -d t.y
cc y.tab.c lex.yy.c t.c
./a.out
```

If you launch the code and run it with the following input:

{
    "firstName": "A",
    "lastName": "B"
}

you'll see that:

1) the code executed in "main" (check file t.y), creates four different pair objects, I then print their memory address and the output is something like (notice different addresses):

```
p 0x7fff52476be8 //(<-memory address for pair p)
print pair: P, Hellov
q 0x7fff52476bc8 //(<-memory address for pair q)
print pair: Q, Hellox
```

2) as soon as I paste the json sample above we hit the "pair" rule twice, the first time for "firstName": "A", the second time for "lastName": "B", I create a new pair in both cases and print the memory address, and they are the same:

```
Creating pair 0x7fff52475c88
print pair: firstName, A
Creating pair 0x7fff52475c88
print pair: lastName, B
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not care what the address of a `pair` is. It is irrelevant to the work being performed with them, and the addresses you are seeing are incidental and without consequence.

Your function `create_pair` does not return a pointer. It is declared with `pair create_pair(…)`, so it returns a `pair`, by value.

In `main`, you define `pair p = create_pair(l, v);`. This creates an automatic object `p`, usually by setting aside space for it on the stack. Then it calls `create_pair`. The value returned by `create_pair` is copied into `p`. Later, when you print `&p`, you are printing the address of `p`, not an address that `create_pair` returned.

Similarly, when you define `pair q = create_pair(l, x);`, you create another object, `q`. Because the lifetime of this object overlaps the lifetime of `p`, they must be in different places, so they have different addresses. When you print `&q`, you see this different address.

Next, consider the code you placed in the Bison rule, `pair p = create_pair($<u_string>1, $<u_value>3);`. Bison executes this code when it is processing a rule. It creates an automatic object, and you print its address. Then execution leaves the scope of this code, and Bison undoubtedly goes on to do other things, and it exits the processing it is currently doing. The lifetimes of automatic objects end, and the data that was on the stack is popped. Later, Bison comes back to this rule. At that point, simply because computers are mechanical in operation, the stack pointer has the same address it did before. So, when a new `p` is created, it happens to be in the same place as the old `p`. Unlike `p` and `q`, which had to be in different places because they existed at the same time, this old `p` and new `p` exist only at different times, so they may be in the same place.

This will not necessarily always happen. If your grammar is more complicated, Bison might have other things in the stack at one time and not another (or perhaps not; the parsing machine Bison produces might not act that way; I do not know offhand). Or if you have the same code in another rule, the stack might be different when that rule is processed.

Comment: Ok, this is clear and definitely the correct answer to my question: THANKS! But let me relaunch on this: how's it possible that when the "members" rule is hit (members: members COMMA pair), and I check the values of $1 and $3 (where $1 is the value returned from members: pair) I see that $1 and $3 are pointing to the same pair? Hope this is clear.

Comment: @user1417009: In the production `pair: string COLON value`, you assign `$$=&p;`. As we have learned, `&p` is the address of an automatic object on the stack. As soon as the code for this rule exits its block (immediately after this assignment), the object lifetime ends, and the stack is reused for something else. So the address you associated with this `pair` is invalid. When execution gets to the rule for `members`, it attempts to use this address, which happens to be pointing to the object for `members`. [Continued…]

Comment: You should not keep addresses of automatic objects in `yylval` objects. You must either copy objects or use pointers to addresses that you dynamically allocate (and later free).

Answer (score 0):

So, what you are seeing is the address of a stack variable changing. Which is perfectly normal. If they all had the same address, you'd get the one value overwrite the other, which wouldn't be very useful.

Edit: When you call a function (from the same caller function, e.g. main), the address of a stack variable is always the same - since the stack started out being the same when the call is made [typically - of course, sometimes compilers do funny things with the stack, so it's not 100% guaranteed]

Edit2: To clarify, if the calls are the same CHAIN of calls, e.g. calling function A from function B from function C, then the stack is OFTEN the same in A, no matter where in B or C the call is made. Of course, if we call function A from function D from function C, then all bets are off as to the address of local variables in A [well, it's most likely fairly similar, but if function D has some huge local variables, it could be very different]. And the caveat that this is TYPICAL still applies. Compilers may well leave the cleanup of the stack "until it's got enough to bother", rather than cleaning up every single call, which means three calls to function A may accumulate some "garbage" on the stack, which doesn't get cleaned up until later.

I'm a little confused as to why you think it should be different from this?

Comment: Well, in case 1, I get always DIFFERENT memory addresses->NOT surprised. As soon as I call it inside a bison action (case 2) the returned "pair" has always the very same address->SURPRISING. Is it clearer now? What actually happens inside the program is that such variables are actually overwritten (e.g.: check what happens when the members rule is satisfied).

Comment: It is not correct to say that when a function is called from the same caller, the stack pointer is the same. Consider when `a` is called from `b` which is called from `c` and when `a` is called from `b` which is called from `d`. Different stack uses in `c` and `d` will cause the stack pointer in `a` to differ. Additionally, other things may affect the stack, such as calling a `a` from a point in `b` where there is a nested scope with additional variables declared.

Comment: Yes, I think tried to say that the stack address isn't guaranteed in the [] section in my post. But typically, if you have multiple calls of function A from function B, then the local variablles in function B will be the same each time. Not guaranteed by any means, but it's quite common. I think we explained roughly the same thing - or I'm confused.